# Implementing ls program in C using dirent.h

Tags: c, ls, dirent.h

I am trying to implement the ls program using the dirent library. It appears that my DIR * mydir is of `<unspecified type>` when I debug with gdb, which says to me that it's as if I am not correctly including the dirent.h header, but I believe that I am correctly including all the required header files.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>

//Specifies whether or not to print hidden files
#define PRINT_HIDDEN 0

void readDirectory(char *dirString[]);

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) 
{
if(argc!=2)
{
printf("Usage: ./ls <directory>\n");
}

readDirectory(argv);    

return 0;
}

void readDirectory(char *dirString[])    
{
DIR *mydir; 
struct dirent *entry;
//Opening the directory and checking if valid
mydir = opendir(dirString[1]);  

if(mydir==NULL){
fprintf(stderr,"ls: cannot access %s: No such file or directory\n",
  dirString);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}   
//Printing directories/files in specified directory
while((entry==readdir(mydir))!=NULL);
{
if(PRINT_HIDDEN)
{
  printf("%s ",entry->d_name);
}
else
{
  if(entry->d_name[0]!='.')
  {
    printf("%s ",entry->d_name);
  }
}
}
printf("\n");
//Closing the directory
closedir(mydir);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what message do you get? In my view, gdb should not care how/what you are correctly or not including...

Comment: @MatsPetersson If I run the program it does not print anything so when I use gdb and this command (gdb) print mydir, I get $1 = (DIR *) 0x601010 and if I use print *mydir, I get $2 = <incomplete type>

Comment: When mydir is null, it doesn't necessarily mean the file or directory doesn't exist.  You should call perror instead.

Comment: That looks like a reasonable address to me. What happens when you step through your code?

Comment: Please indent the code you post to SO with spaces.

Answer (score 6):

Well hidden in badly presented code lie two ugly bugs:

```
while((entry==readdir(mydir))!=NULL);
{
    ...
}
```

Use this instead:

```
while ((entry = readdir(mydir)) != NULL) {
    ...
}
```

`entry` is uninitialized, compiling with warnings enabled as by `gcc -Wall` would have spotted the problem.  The extra `;` at the end of the `while` condition is harder to spot, use a more consistent programming style to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: Is something wrong with the way that I am using opendir    `mydir = opendir(dirString[1]); `

Comment: @user3501476: No, but passing `argv` directly to `readDirectory()` is not convenient, you should define `readDirectory(const char *pathname)` and pass `argv[1]` to it.

Comment: @Anto: I noticed that and edited my response just before your comment, This kind of mistake is a good case for the classic K&R style rules.

Comment: @user3501476: Also fix the `fprintf(stderr,"ls: cannot access %s: No such file or directory\n", dirString);`: pass `dirString[1]` instead.

Comment: @user3501476 Add a exit/return after printing the usage otherwise the program core dump because he cannot access `argv[1]`.